# Null Is not object in React Native routing

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make a simple chat app working with `React Native` for learning. Here is the `App.js`:

```
//import the screens
import Chat from './components/Chat';
//import react navigation
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

//create the navigator
const navigator = createStackNavigator({
  Chat: { screen: Chat },
});

//export it as the root component
export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

I am constantly having an error of `null is not the object`:

[image]

On terminal there is not much information about the error:

```
Loading dependency graph, done.
 DELTA  [android, dev] ..\..\../index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 100.0% (740/740), done.

::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [01/Mar/2019:05:35:34 +0000] "GET /index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [01/Mar/2019:05:35:37 +0000] "POST /symbolicate HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [01/Mar/2019:05:35:39 +0000] "POST /symbolicate HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
```

It seems that `null` was passed into an routing switch. What causes the error?

Answer (score 1):

There can only be one `export default` but there can be multiple `export`
and you can import multiple exports like this

```
import { export1, export2 } from "./componentName"
```